# How to set multiple values in Android XML file

Tags: android, android-imageview

In Imageview i need to use two values for same property(scaleType).

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.70"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

In the above image view for `scaleType` I need to use both the property `fitXY` and `Matrix`.

- `fitXY` - to stretch the image to whole image view
- `Matrix`  - for pinch zooming.

Is it possible to use so or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this [PhotoView library](http://www.senab.co.uk/2012/10/12/photoview-v1-1/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=94ea5cc96d-Android_Weekly_42&utm_medium=email).

According to [spec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) scaleType should containt only one value.

Comment: How to use Photoview library? Jar file is available?

Comment: Here is the link to library and guidelines https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Instead of using library project, is there any way to include in my current project?

Answer (score 1):

For some property you can use multiple values in xml using

> ' | ' . example- android:gravity="right|center_verticle"

This can be used if supported. Not sure if it's supported with this property.